# Synch two ec2 instance for elastic load balancer(ELB) in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I want to use elastic load balancing in aws, I know that how to configure the load balancing from aws console.

I read many blogs and tutorials to configure the load balancing but I still have question regarding the EC2 instances that going to use for load balancing.

1. How the files will get synch b/w all the instances, So that whenever traffic get move to different instance it get updated files and database records.
2. Is there any tool in the AWS console that can do it?
3. Can we achieve it using EBS, I means can we use one EBS volume for different instances?

I'll be thankful if you can suggest me the best way to implement it.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your EC2 instances need to be exact copies of each other, meaning they need to run exactly the same software stack. As far as the database is concerned you need have a single backend database (unless you are sharding your data) If you want more reliability and faster read performance you want to setup database replication. (You can accomplish this with RDS)
2. Use RDS for database backend.
3. More than EBS I think to have your instances exactly the same you want to use AMIs. AMIs are Amazon instance images that are based off an EBS Snapshot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. I suppose I can setup the database replication b/w two local database server of different Instances without using RDS? So if I go with database replication then no need to use RDS, m i right?